# LoopJ AndroidAsyncHttp PUT, how to do?

Tags: android, http, asp.net-web-api, android-async-http

I need some help correcting my approach for using the following API > https://github.com/Privo/PRIVO-Hub/wiki/Web-Services-API-Reference#update-user-display-name.

I am unsure of how to send a JSON object for update using LoopJ AndroidAsyncHttp PUT. I am receiving the following error response

{"message":"Error: null","validationErrors":[]."responseTimestamp":141936124612,"totalCount":-1,"status":"failed","resultCount":-1,"entity":null}

How am I doing this wrong?

```
AsyncHttpClient client = null;
String authorizationHeader = "token_type", "" + " " + "access_token", "");
client.addHeader("Authorization", authorizationHeader);
client.addHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
client.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
String requestBody = "displayName=" + "hardcodedDisplayName";
String requestURL = "https://privohub.privo.com/api/" + "account/public/saveDisplayName?" + requestBody;
client.put(requestURL, new ResponseHandler(myClass.this, "displayName", new OnResponseHandler() {
@Override
public void onSuccess(int statusCode, String apiName, JSONObject response) {
   if (statusCode == 200) {
      Log.i(TAG, "Seems to be working")

   }
}

@Override
public void onFailure(int statusCode, String apiName, String responseMessage) {
   Log.i(TAG, "Fail: " + responseMessage); 
}

@Override
public void onFailure(int statusCode, String apiName, JASONArray errorResponse) {
   Log.i(TAG, "Fail: " + errorResponse);
}

@Override
public void onFailure(int statusCode, String apiName, JSONObject errorResponse) {
   if (errorResponse != null) {
      Log.i(TAG, "Fail: " + errorResponse);
   }
}

}));
```

Comment: curious about the choice for a client in android... http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html  .. where did you come up with java httpclient on android? i would think ( loopj, volley, okhttp,  apache's android client ) may be better fits??

Comment: I am trying to use loopj. http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.loopj.android/android-async-http/1.4.3/com/loopj/android/http/AsyncHttpClient.java. Thing is, this is my first attempt at it. I think my params for PUT may be incorrect maybe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are using [AsyncHttpClient](https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client),

Use the [preparePut](http://asynchttpclient.github.io/async-http-client/apidocs/reference/com/ning/http/client/AsyncHttpClient.html#preparePut(java.lang.String)) and [AsyncHttpClient.BoundRequestBuilder](http://asynchttpclient.github.io/async-http-client/apidocs/reference/com/ning/http/client/AsyncHttpClient.BoundRequestBuilder.html) builder as in the [examples/readme](https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client),

```
AsyncHttpClient client =  new AsyncHttpClient(); // not null
// other code here
String requestBody = "displayName=" + "hardcodedDisplayName";
String requestURL = "https://privohub.privo.com/api/" + "account/public/saveDisplayName?" + requestBody;
client.preparePut(requestURL)  // sets the urls the put request and gets a AsyncHttpClient.BoundRequestBuilder
   .setBody(requestBody) // sets the body of the put request
   .execute(new AsyncCompletionHandler<Response>(){

        @Override
        public Response onCompleted(Response response) throws Exception{
            // Do something with the Response
            // ...
            return response;
        }

        @Override
        public void onThrowable(Throwable t){
            // Something wrong happened.
        }
    });
```

Comment: The asyncHttpClient.preparePut should be client.preparePut? I am receiving errors on asyncHttpClient.preparePut.

Comment: yep you are right.  Check the edit.  Are using this AsyncHttpClient library https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client  ?

Comment: I am not using that library. My AsyncHttpClient has the package com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient. preparePut is undefined for my client object for AsyncHttpClient. I will +1 for helping, this is closest I have gotten with this. Thanks!

Comment: heh, well that explains that.